# dynamically returning javascript function from controller and passing it to cshtml

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My Controller is...

```
public ActionResult CreateEmailStep5()
{
    MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel();
    mvm.myStringProperty = @"$(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#Help').MyTour(
        {
          tourType: 'step',
          overlayOpacity: 0.5,
          .......
          .......
        });
    });"
    return View(mvm);
}
```

what am i trying with my .cshtml is like....

```
@model MyProj.ViewModels.MyViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    Model.myStringProperty;
</script>
```

I tried several things like Response.Write, HtmlDecode and HtmlEncode...
what happening is... My Single Quote is being converted to its ascii " ' "

when i am trying...

```
Response.Write(@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.myStringProperty).ToString());
```

instead of

```
Model.myStringProperty;
```

in my .cshtml then its giving erro $ is not defined while i have added all required links

Comment: Why are you dynamically building the javascript in your view? Do you intend to pass some values to your javascript?

Comment: i need it because i don't know how much step i need to implement.. this info will come from DataBase

Comment: let me know if there is a way to do like this

Comment: basically i need to create javascript function Dynamically on server an then i want to inject it to .cshtml....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert your razor variable to html 'type'

Try using

```
@Html.Raw(Model.myStringProperty)
```